Xcode: different debug and release version
I didn’t change any settings, but my Xcode start showing me two options in “Target” → “General” → “Version”: The first one is “Debug” and second is “Release”. You can see in the attached image below:

But if we create a new app then it shows like in give image below:

I want to remove the “Debug” and “Release” options under “Version”.

The interesting question in my mind is how they got out of sync in the first place. Did someone edit this (by tapping the “+” button), or do you have some CI/CD process that bumped one or the other?

I think the it due to first case, some one edit it by (by tapping the “+” button) because we did't add CI/CD process.

You can click on the “…” button, edit them to be the same again (and get rid of the extra “iOS” entries while there, if you want), and then the UI will collapse to a single version number string.

FWIW, I find the Xcode (15.3) UI suffers from some UI idiosyncrasies. I.e., I had to tap on the background to dismiss the dialog. It wouldn't save it for me if I just navigated away while this popup was presented. Likewise, even though it now saved it correctly, the target settings UI is not updated correctly. I found that I had to tap away from the target settings and then back for the version string to be displayed correctly.
Also, make sure the two version strings are identical (including whitespace). If one or the other has additional spaces around the version string, it will not recognize them as being identical.

I make the version same for both Debug and Release, but it still showing the same @Rob

@QaziAmmar – In my answer, I’ve added a few caveats regarding the flaky Xcode UI when editing these version strings.

FWIW, Xcode 15.4 Beta (15F5021i) exhibits the same UI idiosyncrasies. I have opened ticket FB13766999 with Apple.
